# set time between actions in a command in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i have a question, i would like to know how i could do various actions at the same time, with timers, in this case this is my code so i can help you understand my case!

```
const discord = require ("discord.js")
const config = require('../config.json')

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const memberTarget = message.mentions.members.first();
    const general = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "general");
    const nazi = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "nazi");
    const stripties = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "stripties");
    const reportado = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "reportado");
    const highquality = message.guild.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "high-quality");

    if (memberTarget.voice.channel)
        memberTarget.voice.setChannel(nazi)
        if (memberTarget.voice.channel === nazi)
        memberTarget.voice.setChannel(stripties)
        if (memberTarget.voice.channel === reportado)
        memberTarget.voice.setChannel(reportado)
        
    

      
}      
module.exports.help = {
    name: 'tour'
}
```

i want to get that memberTarget i mention to move him through the channels, i want probably 2seconds or one second through each event, i mean he moves to first channel, then 1 second later, second channel, etc etc, ty a lot! i hope i did good at trying to explain!

Comment: Using [setTimeout()](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/timers-in-node/#controlling-the-time-continuum-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `setTimeOut` in promise. I can give you a example like this.

```js
function firstEvent(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("I'm the first event");
            resolve()
        }, 1000);
    })
}
function secondEvent(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("I'm the second event");
            resolve()
        }, 1000);
    })
}
function thirdEvent(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("I'm the third event");
            resolve()
        }, 1000);
    })
}
function forthEvent(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("I'm the forth event");
            resolve()
        }, 1000);
    })
}


async function setGapBetween() {
    await firstEvent();
    await secondEvent();
    await thirdEvent();
    await forthEvent();
}

setGapBetween();
```

Comment: perfect, exactly what i wanted!